# How to systematically replace <NA> row with preceding values in R data frame

Tags: r

I have a data that looks like this:

```
FOO,yyy,Unigene126925_All,Unigene137063_All,0.238087
,,Unigene126925_All,Unigene24551_All,0.374231
,,Unigene126925_All,Unigene31835_All,0.367897
BAR,xxx,Unigene126925_All,Unigene165366_All,0.247844
,,Unigene126925_All,Unigene111784_All,0.344493
```

Which after reading it with the following code:

```
 dt <- read.csv("http://dpaste.com/1612639/plain/",header=FALSE,fill=FALSE,na.strings = "")
 # The <NA> coercion here is intentional.
```

It produces this result:

```
> dt
    V1   V2                V3                V4       V5
1  FOO  yyy Unigene126925_All Unigene137063_All 0.238087
2 <NA> <NA> Unigene126925_All  Unigene24551_All 0.374231
3 <NA> <NA> Unigene126925_All  Unigene31835_All 0.367897
4  BAR  xxx Unigene126925_All Unigene165366_All 0.247844
5 <NA> <NA> Unigene126925_All Unigene111784_All 0.344493
```

What I want to do is to replace the `<NA>` cells with the preceding values, yielding this:

```
FOO yyy Unigene126925_All Unigene137063_All 0.238087
FOO yyy Unigene126925_All  Unigene24551_All 0.374231
FOO yyy Unigene126925_All  Unigene31835_All 0.367897
BAR xxx Unigene126925_All Unigene165366_All 0.247844
BAR xxx Unigene126925_All Unigene111784_All 0.344493
```

In the above example the 2nd row has NA, it has to take the values for V1 and V2 columns from the preceding rows that contain the values.

How can I achieve that in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `na.locf` function (package [`zoo`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html)):

```
library(zoo)

dt$V1 <- na.locf(dt$V1) 
dt$V2 <- na.locf(dt$V2)
```

or in one shot:

```
dt <- na.locf(dt)
```

obtaining

```
> dt
   V1  V2                V3                V4       V5
1 FOO yyy Unigene126925_All Unigene137063_All 0.238087
2 FOO yyy Unigene126925_All  Unigene24551_All 0.374231
3 FOO yyy Unigene126925_All  Unigene31835_All 0.367897
4 BAR xxx Unigene126925_All Unigene165366_All 0.247844
5 BAR xxx Unigene126925_All Unigene111784_All 0.344493
```